# php job scheduler NOT yet fired

Tags: php, scheduler

I am using php job scheduler for some offline process. I was added a job and give 1 min time interval. After 1 min it shows only NOT yet fired. When refresh the job link directly some row affected in th mysql database table. Can any one try to help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Which scheduler are you using? Can you just use a regular cron?

Comment: I am using phpJobScheduler. It was downloaded from this link http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/